# How do I make Chrome block absolutely all pop-ups?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome's pop-up blocker blocks most pop-ups, but it allows them if they were the effect of direct user actions.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587692/4356188

Porn sites are very annoying because they trick the browser into thinking that I voluntarily cause pop-ups to open. Like when I click the play button on a video, and an ad for an adult game opens in a separate window.

How do I make Chrome block absolutely all pop-ups, whether I clicked a button to open it or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **How do I make Chrome block absolutely all pop-ups**

I have to suggest you use the [Popup Blocker (strict)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/popup-blocker-strict/aefkmifgmaafnojlojpnekbpbmjiiogg?hl) Chrome extension because you asked specifically "*How do I make Chrome block absolutely all pop-ups*" and below are the specific instructions about configuring this to make just that happen and never even prompt for an override in the first place from what my testing results concluded for me.

Regardless of any scrutiny this answer may bring from others, give it a simple try and configure the options as outlined below and you'll see it works as expected as I did. I will also provide a method for you to easily test before and after at the bottom of the detailed configuration instructions.

---

> ### Detailed Configuration Instructions
>
> 1. Install the 4.5 star rated [Popup Blocker (strict)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/popup-blocker-strict/aefkmifgmaafnojlojpnekbpbmjiiogg?hl)
>      Chrome extension
>
>    [image]
>
>    > **Strictly block all popup requests from any website**
>    >
>    > ```
>    > Supported blocking methods:
>    >  1. window.open
>    > ```
> 2. In the Chrome address bar paste in `chrome://extensions/` and press **Enter**
> 3. Ensure it's turned **On** and then click on the **Details** button
>
>    [image]
> 4. Click on the **Extension options** configuration icon
>
>    [image]
> 5. You will want to ensure these settings are set with these values—and be sure to <kbd>**`Save`**</kbd>:
>
>    - **Maximum number of popup requests for a single page:** `1`
>    - **Timeout for displaying each popup (in seconds):** `1`
>    - **Countdown for performing the last action (in seconds):** `1`
>    - **Default action when a popup is requested:** `deny request`
>    - **Display the total number of blocked requests in the toolbar icon**: `unchecked`
>    - **Prevent page redirection for 2 seconds after a popup is requested**: `checked`
>    - **Ignore popup notification when possible (not recommended)**: `checked` [image]
>    - **Whitelist destinations:** `Blank/Delete All`
>    - **Whitelist sources:** `Blank/Delete All`
>    - **Save** (*Very Important*) [image]

---

### Testing Before and After

- [Test your popup blocker](http://tools.add0n.com/popup-blocker.html)
- [Test your popup blocker software](http://www.popuptest.com/)

Answer (score 2):

To do better than the pop-up blocker that is built-in into Chrome,
you will need to use third-party extensions.

There are quite a few extensions available.
I have listed some of them below in the order of their notes on the Chrome store.

- [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en)
  Noted 5-star by 19197 users. This extension is the most recommended.
- [Popup Blocker Pro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/popup-blocker-pro/kiodaajmphnkcajieajajinghpejdjai?hl=en)
  Noted 4-star by 6984 users.
- [JustBlock Security](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/justblock-security/hiajdlfgbgnnjakkbnpdhmhfhklkbiol?hl=en)
  Noted 3.5 stars by only 2060 users, so the least recommended.
- [ScriptSafe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptsafe/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf?hl=en)
  Although this is not just a pop-up blocker, I also recommend this extension
  with which one can block the execution of JavaScript from
  unauthorized sources, so can disable the script before it launches
  the pop-up in a way not trapped by the blocker.
  This extension does not suit the working style of everybody but makes
  surfing safer.